# Why is there so much empty space around the label of a material design button?

Tags: android, button, material-design

There is too much empty space around a material design button, but for my implementation I would like to reduce it a little. Padding (setting it to 0dp) has no effect.

[image]

Here is the layout.xml:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_close"
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="CLOSE"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: The space is there to match the space above and below the text. And that space is there, so that the "tap-target" is large enough be an easy target for people to tap it with their fingers.
I would suggest that you just leave it be. If you really need to change it, you should look into the theme that defines the look of the button. Their you should find what sets the spacing. I believe it is some inset specified for the background.

Comment: You could set the padding to negative though like padding=-5dp

Comment: @Ridcully. The button was in the corner of the window, the problem was that sometimes it overlapped other content. I solved the layout issue by simply changing the position of the button - now it is below all window content - horizontally centred.

Comment: @azeemofwalsall Good for you, finding a better solution instead of trying to force something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height and width of a button as wrap content then add the padding or margin of your choice

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap content"
        android:layout_height="wrap content"
        android:text="CLOSE"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Already tried that, it doesn't work. It could be a material design stipulation that there must be that much space at the sides of the lable.